# How can I save unique user data on my site?

Tags: php, database, mysql, user-meta, user-registration

I am trying to find a way to allow registered users on my site create lists of data and save them. I'm having trouble finding a way to save the list they create to the database of my site. I am familiar with programming and I can't find a plugin that does this.

How can I do this?

Comment: Sorry, but you will have to be more specific than that. What "lists of data" do you mean? Do you want users to be able to enter specific data into tables? How do you imagine should it work? What will be done with the entered data? Please edit your question to include this information.

Comment: In particular, do people just need to deal with a list as a chunk of stuff, or do they need to delve into its specific contents? E.g., "show the list of Joe's room wall colors" vs. "show a list of everyone who has a blue kitchen, a red bedroom, and a pink living room."

Comment: You'll have to create an interface for the users to insert those data and use a function like [`add_user_meta `](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_user_meta/) to save the data related to the user.